# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, wordpress, buddypress

I bought a WordPress theme and I am having several errors and which hopefully would fix my BuddyPress conflict with the Theme's jQuery and AJAX.

My problem is I'm getting 2 errors:

1. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null`

   `init:function(tabid, dselected){
       var menuitems=document.getElementById(tabid).getElementsByTagName("a")`

   `Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null (repeated 2 times)`
2. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null`

   `buildcontentdivs:function(setting){
       var alldivs=document.getElementById(setting.id).getElementsByTagName("div")`

   `Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null`

I don't know how to fix this as I'm not a programmer. I only know HTML, CSS and basic WordPress PHP.

Comment: Wait, you *have* access to jQuery?

Comment: the error tells you that the respective Elements do not exist in the DOM node of the browser's document. Likely a javascript is executing without the web-document being present or lacking html content sent from the server due to a serverside issue...

Answer (score 1):

In each case, getElementById isn't finding the desired element.  Since you don't give any context for these calls, can't help any more than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put jquery in the `<head>` it runs before the elements are rendered, so that's why it maybe returning null.